# SQL Server Insert If Not Exists - No Primary Key

Tags: sql-server, insert, exists, not-exists

I have `Table A` and `Table B`.

`Table A` contains data from another source.

`Table B` contains data that is inserted from `Table A` along with data from other tables. I have done the initial insert of data from `A` to `B` but now what I am trying to do is insert the records that do not exist already in `Table B` from `Table A` on a daily basis. Unfortunately, there is no primary key or unique identifier in `Table A` which is making this difficult.

`Table A` contains a field called `file_name` which has values that looks like this:
`this_is_a_file_name_01011980.txt` 
There can be duplicate values in this column (multiple files from the same date).

In `Table B` I created a column `data_date` which extracts the date from the `table a.file_name` field. There is also a `load_date` field which just uses `GETDATE()` at the time the data is inserted.

I am thinking I can somehow compare the dates in these tables to decide what needs to be inserted. For example:
If the file date from `Table A` (would need to extract again) is greater than the `load_date` of `Table B`, then insert these records into `Table B`.

Let me know if any clarification is needed.

Comment: Why can't you just compare rows on all `Table A` columns to see if the row exists or not in `Table B`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use exists or except. With the explanation here it seems like except would make short work of this. Something like this.

```
insert tableB
select * from tableA
except
select * from tableB
```

Comment: Well not `SELECT *` since OP states they've added extra columns to `Table B`

Comment: @TabAlleman of course not * but there is zero in the way of details here.